# Программа завершилась с кодом 1073741855 (0x4000001f)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Пробовал гуглить по этому коду, но ничего не нашел. 
Вообще, я не удивлен крешу, так как тут 20+ потоков, которые вызывают WinApi-функции через библиотеку обертку. Каждый поток делает скриншоты а потом по пикселяи эти скриншоты обрабатывает.

Ошибка вылазит не всегда, но регулярно.

В общем, меня интересует скорее как перехватить эту ошибку, чем ее исправление. Try-Catch не помог. Всм. нету никакого исключения, просто крэш с выводом.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить под отладчиком, может остановится где нужно. Хотя, это .NET...

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: А что необычного в отладке .NET-программ?

Comment: @VladD ну, обычные отладчики для нативного кода типа того же OllyDBG бесполезны чуть менее, чем полностью. Как у DebugAPI отношения с .NET я тоже не знаю.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов: У Visual Studio прекрасный отладчик. У автора же есть исходники? Если нету, то справился бы WinDbg.

Comment: Проблема решилась. 
Просто однажды перед вылетом, студия показала, где косяк и приложение крешнулось через секунду. 
Была проблема с тем, что объект использовался в разных потоках одновременно. Что объясняет не постоянство ошибки, но не объясняет почему try-catch не помог. Ну да ладно.